# Adding options with different argument types using Python's argparse module

Tags: python, command-line-interface, argparse

I'm trying to add a command-line option that takes three arguments, where the last two must be integers.

```
$ myapp --opt str_value 2 4
```

First I tried something like this.

```py
parser.add_argument(
    '--opt',
    nargs=3,
    metavar='<str> <int> <int>',
    help="...",
)
```

But the help then looks like this (which was expected).

```
options:
  --opt <str> <int> <int> <str> <int> <int> <str> <int> <int>
```

When omitting `metavar`, it becomes unclear that the last two values must be integers.

Anyway, I don't like the above approach because I would have to check manually that the first argument is valid and the last two arguments are integers.

So I tried using [parents](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#parents), but couldn't implement it correctly in my existing code.

```py
# Wrong: This does not work

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='...')
parser.add_argument('--compress', action='store_true', help='compress images')

parent = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
parent.add_argument(
    '--opt',
    type=int,
    nargs=2,
    metavar='<int>',
    help='...',
)

foo_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[parent])
foo_parser.add_argument(
    'str_value',
    choices=['str1', 'str2', 'str3']
    help='...',
)

args = parser.parse_args()
foo_args = resize_method.parse_args()
```

Maybe parents would be an appropriate solution, but even if I could get it to work, I would have a new problem in showing `str_value` as a positional argument in the help, separate from the `--opt` option.

I ended up implementing each valid string argument as a separate option, which I don't really like, although it works.

```py
parser.add_argument(
    '--str1', type=int, nargs=2, metavar='<int>', help='...'
)
parser.add_argument(
    '--str2', type=int, nargs=2, metavar='<int>', help='...'
)
parser.add_argument(
    '--str3', type=int, nargs=2, metavar='<int>', help='...'
)
```

Just to mention, subcommands are not a solution for me either, because I want to be able to combine `--opt` with other flag options.

Is there a way to make this work (with a good help structure)?

Comment: [`metavar` accepts a tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#metavar). Do `metavar=(“<str>”, “<int>”, “<int>”)`.

Comment: `parents` does not add any functionality.

Comment: Consider defining a custom action as well, which lets you convert the two integers to `int` objects during parsing.

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#metavar):

> Different values of `nargs` may cause the metavar to be used multiple times. Providing a tuple to `metavar` specifies a different display for each of the arguments:
>
> ```
> >>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
> >>> parser.add_argument('-x', nargs=2)
> >>> parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs=2, metavar=('bar', 'baz'))
> >>> parser.print_help()
> usage: PROG [-h] [-x X X] [--foo bar baz]
>
> options:
>  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
>  -x X X
>  --foo bar baz
> ```

So specify `metavar=('<str>', '<int>', '<int>')`.

Comment: Somehow I overlooked this possibility in the documentation. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

As others wrote, giving a tuple metavar that matches the nargs gives the desired usage/help display:

```
In [20]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser();
    ...: parser.add_argument(
    ...:     '--opt',
    ...:     nargs=3,
    ...:     metavar=('<str>', '<int>', '<int>'),
    ...:     help="...",
    ...: );

In [21]: parser.print_help()
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--opt <str> <int> <int>]

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --opt <str> <int> <int>
                        ...

In [22]: parser.parse_args('--opt foo 2 3'.split())
Out[22]: Namespace(opt=['foo', '2', '3'])
```

An alternative would let it display as '--opt OPT OPT OPT' and give more details in the `help` string.

`parents` is just a way of copying the `add_argument` of one parser to a new one.  It does not add any functionality.

The other task is testing and converting those three strings.

The `type` function only sees one argument string at a time, so can't (readily) distinguish between the string and int arguments.

The `action` `__call__` method does get all (3) strings.  So a custom `Action` class could test and convert the 2nd and 3rd, before saving them to the `namespace`.  The code to do this would look a lot like the code you'd write to process `args.opt` after parsing.  You'll have to look at the `argparse.py` code to copy and modify a existing Action subclass.

But I think a custom 'Action' class is worth the work only if you have several arguments with this type of input.  Otherwise, doing the post-argparse processing will be simplest.

You don't get extra credit for doing all the input handling within the `parser`.

```
In [27]: args=parser.parse_args('--opt foo bar 3'.split())
In [29]: try:
    ...:     opts = [args.opt[0], int(args.opt[1]), int(args.opt[2])]
    ...: except ValueError:
    ...:     parser.error('opt arguments should be str,int,int')
    ...:     
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [--opt <str> <int> <int>]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: opt arguments should be str,int,int
....
```

Comment: It's just this one argument with this type of input. I considered writing a custom `action` class for this, but yes, it makes perfect sense to process and test the arguments _after_ they are parsed. I was also thinking about [defining a custom type and function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type), that would also make sense, right?

Comment: the `type` function gets one string at a tune, which it "converts" or objects.  In your case it would get, in succesive calls, `"string_value", "2", "4'.  I can see writing `try: return int(str); except ValueError: return str`.  That would convert 
 the values that it can, but won't object if the user gives the 'wrong' mix of numbers and strings.  It comes down to how much control you want over what the user gives you.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom Action to handle this situation:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# main.py
import argparse
from argparse import ArgumentParser, Namespace
from collections.abc import Sequence
from typing import Any


class Opt3Action(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(
        self,
        parser: ArgumentParser,
        namespace: Namespace,
        values: str | Sequence[Any] | None,
        option_string: str | None = None,
    ) -> None:
        args = []
        casts = [str, int, int]

        for cast, value in zip(casts, values or []):
            try:
                value = cast(value)
                args.append(value)
            except ValueError:
                parser.exit(1, f"{value!r} must be of type {cast.__name__}\n")
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, args)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--opt", nargs=3, action=Opt3Action, help="Must be str int int")
options = parser.parse_args()
print(options)
```

Some sample runs

```bash
# Get help
$ python3 main.py -h           
usage: main.py [-h] [--opt OPT OPT OPT]

options:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  --opt OPT OPT OPT  Must be str int int

# Happy path
$ python3 main.py --opt foo 5 51
Namespace(opt=['foo', 5, 51])

# Second element is not an int
$ python3 main.py --opt foo bar 51
'bar' must be of type int

# Last element is not an int
$ python3 main.py --opt foo 5 51x 
'51x' must be of type int
```

#### Notes

- You can safely assume that `values` will be a list of 3 elements, the `nargs=3` part ensures it
- After we validated and converted all values, the `setattr` line will set those values